# How can I provide login feature to a Jekyll site?

Tags: authentication, jekyll, disqus

How can I provide login feature to a Jekyll site?

I'm not sure if I am asking the correct question. Basically, I'm setting up a Jekyll blog for an intranet, and when any person (who connected to the intranet) comments on the blog, I want the site to use Windows's username as the display-name of the comment. In this way, I would know which comment is posted by which user (connected to the intranet), and I don't want the commenters to choose any other name as display-name to discourage trolling. Can it be done?

I was thinking if I could force the poster to login before commenting (and verify it Windows's athentication somehow), then maybe that username can be used as display-name. I'm not sure if that is possible, as I don't know if Jekyll provides that much flexibility.

I'm using Disqus as comment-provider. I may switch to a suitable comment-provider if required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jekyll is a static blog, so it can't display dynamic data as username.

EDIT:
Disqus is hosted on the cloud and you use javascript to bring it from the cloud to your static jekyll powered website.

So if you want to do the same, you have to build an application that is completely outside of jekyll, a Sign On Web Services and query it with Javascript in your jekyll blog.

Comment: Comment-provider like Disqus asks to sign in before commenting. How is that possible? Can't we do something there?

Comment: +1 for the edit. Do you have any idea as to how much effort do I need to invest in order to build a hello-world web service (for a proof of concept) **and** use it from Jekyll? I know WCF and ASP.NET WebService, but don't know how to integrate it with Jekyll-site. Any vague idea? Would it be easy or tough?

Comment: Little bit. Wrote an ASP.NET HelloWorldService, and trying to call it using learning JQuery. Currently it gives error, so I'm struggling.

Comment: if it is host an another domain, you should use JSONP

Comment: The HelloWorldService is running on my local pc (I started it from VisuslStudio without even hosting) and I'm able to call it using jQuery. I think from now I can work on it. I did the POC. Now I feel a bit confident (even though Web/Javascript/Jekyll/Ruby/Liqiud are all new things for me). Thanks for the help. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Try Google/Facebook/Twitter api, use these api to authorize your client.

Comment: This is also the direction I would suggest.